# Firebase storage rule resource variable returns null

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I wrote a simple rule,

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /image/{fileName} {
      allow read: if resource != null;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Then I added a file in `/image` folder in the default bucket. Using the `Rules playground` simulator tries a read request to the file and it failed. It is saying the resource is actually a null.

[image: screen capture of Rules playground]
Any ideas why? From their documentation it seems like it should not do this or am I missing something? Any help will be highly appreciated.

(Update) Following was what I originally tried doing, 
[image: checking for size]

--- (Update in response to Franks post) 
Hi Frank, I tried exactly what you suggested, still no luck :(. Attaching the screenshot here.

[image: screen shot 1]

[image: screen-shot 2]

(Update) Frank's suggestion is correct, the file name mismatch was the issue as you originally suggested. The actual file name is `scribble.jpg` and I typed `scibble.jpg` in the simulator. After correcting, it was working as expected.

Comment: What is your rule trying to enforce?  I can't figure out what `resource != null` is supposed to mean.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a more complete rule like `resource.size > 0` in one of my projects, but then can't reproduce it in another project. If you try to read the same file from code with these rules, does it work? If so, it might be a bug in the rules playground in the Firebase console.

Comment: @DougStevenson I was actually trying to use ``resource.size`` in the rule. I updated the post with the picture of that run. Digging deeper is where I ended up checking ``resource != null``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I thought I could reproduce the problem, after carefully copy/pasting the paths of some existing files, I can now no longer reproduce this in any project/test.

[image]

No idea what's going on for you, but I recommend copy/pasting the file names/paths as I did. Especially check for training spaces with in the file name, and in the `Location` value you enter in the playground, as they are incredibly easy to overlook and will cause the rules to fail.

Comment: ---
I tried exactly what you suggested, still no luck :(. Attaching the screenshot here. Please check my updated post. No trailing space either.

Comment: Hey @kibudude. I just restarted from scratch to try and reproduce the problem you're having, and unfortunate can't get the error anymore unless I enter a non-existing path. I'm sort of lost on how to further troubleshoot this. You might want to have a look at the network traffic to see if that contains any hint as to what's going on. I'd also recommend seeing if the rules are correctly enforced for you when you access the file from code.

Comment: Hi @frank-van-puffelen, many thanks. I will try to access it from code and see how it behaves.

Comment: Hi @frank-van-puffelen, I did try with code and it works fine. At any rate then I went back to the simulator tried to give it a very hard look again to see if I am missing something. After looking it carefully, I found the problem. It was actually quite stupid of me, the file name mismatch was the issue as you originally suggested. The actual file name is ``scribble.jpg`` and I typed ``scibble.jpg`` in the simulator. It fooled my eyes somehow. The good news is the simulator works just fine.

Comment: Oh wow, that's a hard type to spot. Glad you got it working after all, and thanks for updating here!